# ssh connection timed out

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh, gitlab

I am not able to ssh in git to github or bitbucket or gitlab.
I typically have the following error message: how can I avoid it?

========== output ============

```
ssh -T git@github.com -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -v
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.255.113] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.30.255.113 port 22: Connection timed out
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.255.112] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.30.255.112 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: I suggest to first test connection with telnet: `telnet github.com 22`. If this test is successful, you can exclude a firewall and know that sshd is running.

Comment: Don't worry, ssh questions (all 18K of them) are on topic, especially when they are related to Git, a tool used for development.

Comment: @Cyrus it's not working
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
not only with github but also bitbucket & gitlab.

Comment: `sudo nmap 192.30.255.113 -p 22` may also be helpful

Comment: Pretty sure, your corporate firewall is blocking all outgoing traffic to ssh. Verify it with some other network.

Comment: @acsrujan yes the isp have blocked the port 22.Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The ISP has Blocked the Port 22. **Solved** !

Answer (score 1):

Kill the SSH process and restart it. It has solved me similar issues. I have found that multiple instances of SSH, in that case you have to kill them all.

Answer (score 0):

This error message is typical when

- the remote ssh daemon is not running (which is not the case here regarding GitHub, BitBucket or GitLab)
- the local port 22 is blocked for outgoing connection (which is generally the case when working in enterprise: only http(s) is open, not ssh)

The OP confirms the ISP has blocked port 22.

See if you can use an https url instead:

```
cd /path/to/my/local/repo
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<user>/<repo>
```

Note that with **[trystack](http://trystack.org/)**, you might need to [follow this gist](https://gist.github.com/samvarankashyap/ccc07bb6c2ced8e80434)

> Click the Security Groups tab, click Edit Rules, and add a couple rules:

```
imcp, from port: -1, to port: -1, cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp, from port: 22, to port: 22, cidr: your.ip.address.here/32
```

Comment: i create a instance in trystack and tried to ssh into it but it also fails.
same connection timedout.
i tried [SDF](http://sdf.org/) as refered in [free-public-ssh-server-for-testing-purposes](https://serverfault.com/questions/185153/free-public-ssh-server-for-testing-purposes), it also fails.

Comment: @SARAVANANSYR with the same "timed out" error message? What is the git version over there?

Comment: @ VonC git version 2.13.3. i tink there's some problem with ssh

Comment: @SARAVANANSYR but only on trystack?

Comment: failing in all providers.

Comment: Ok, what is your OS, from which you are trying to connect with SSH to a remote server?

Comment: UBUNTU 16.04 LTS. using built in terminal and terminator for linux.ssh to trystack & pushing commits to github, bitbucket,gitlab.

Comment: @SARAVANANSYR I have edited the answer with a step to follow specific to trystack: can you check it out?

Comment: the isp have blocked the port 22.Thanks

Comment: @SARAVANANSYR Good point. I have included it in the answer. Don't forget to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer