# how to resolve port 22 connection timeout

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

```
ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

My firewalls are disabled and I still get connection time out. What should I do?

Comment: Not an answer, anyway to enable verbose ssh:
`GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git clone example`

You can even increase verbosity with 
`GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone example`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589682/ssh-connect-to-host-github-com-port-22-connection-timed-out

Comment: Can you show some of the commands you were running? Is the repo you are pushing/pulling from public? Did you enter the url correctly? If you are using SSH, does you computer have the right keys?  Please provide more information so we can help! :)

Comment: Do you have an entry in your /etc/hosts file for bitbucket.org? If so, take it out.

Comment: ➜  amfrost_crm git:(master) git pull origin master
ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
 this is the request i am using @machetazo

Comment: Does your computer have the right  keys to use SSH? @gaurav-singh

Comment: i found the solution to this just change the ip address of the host in /etc/hosts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssh connection timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518078/ssh-connection-timed-out)

Answer (score 13):

Looks like you have issues with the default SSH port and they could be avoided by using another port. This is a common issue.

Basically, you can use port 443 instead of 22.

- For **Github**, the answer is:

> To set this in your ssh config, edit the file at ~/.ssh/config, and
> add this section:
>
> ```
> Host github.com
>     Hostname ssh.github.com
>     Port 443
> ```

- **BitBucket**: Answers below confirmed you can still do this even though it was supposed to be discontinued on June 15, 2011:

  ```
   Host bitbucket.org
    Hostname  altssh.bitbucket.org
    Port  443
  ```
- For **Gitlab**, the ssh config looks like this. Update the IdentityFile to match your local private key:

  ```
   Host gitlab.com
       Hostname altssh.gitlab.com
       User git
       Port 443
       PreferredAuthentications publickey
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab
  ```

Sources:

- https://about.gitlab.com/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/
- https://help.github.com/en/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port
- https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/enabling-ssh-access-to-git-repositories-in-bitbucket-server-776640358.html

Answer (score 0):

For Bitbucket this worked for me:

```
Host bitbucket.org
 Hostname  altssh.bitbucket.org
 Port  443
```

Answer (score 0):

I am bit late to answer but my config file works for both GitHub and BitBucket

```
Host bitbucket.org
Hostname  altssh.bitbucket.org
Port  443

Host github.com
Hostname ssh.github.com
Port 443
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

```
    Host github.com
    Hostname ssh.github.com
    Port 443
    User git
```

**I suggest you reading this [github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port)**